# Working with Git branches - Viewing / Adding and Commiting to them

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I've been reading about working with Git `branches` and I know how to create them and get into them, but what I don't understand is that how come when I do an `ls` when I'm inside a new branch it shows the same files as the `master` branch?

I'm trying to create a slightly different version of a library and I wanted to put it into another branch -- but I am confused why the branch shows it has all the files already?

Also, to commit to the branch I assume I just `git checkout myBranch` and then run the `add`, `commit` and `push` commands once inside the specific branch?

**Edit:** I assume I see the sames files because I am in the same "physical location" and it doesn't take into account the branch I am in, I guess I got confused by [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-branches) mentioning it.

So I guess my additional question is, is there a way to view files within the branch you are currently in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I don't understand is that how come when I do an `ls` when I'm inside a new branch it shows the same files as the `master` branch?

In Git, a branch is simply a pointer to a commit. Branches "contain" multiple commits insofar as each commit knows its own parents.

If you create a new branch `newbranch` from `master`, `newbranch` will initially point to the same commit as `master`:

```
C  [master][newbranch]
|
B
|
A
```

There will be no difference between the two branches until you create a new commit in one of the branches, which also moves its branch pointer, e.g. creating a new commit in `newbranch` will result in something like this:

```
D  [newbranch]
|
C  [master]
|
B
|
A
```

> So I guess my additional question is, is there a way to view files within the branch you are currently in?

As mentioned above, a branch points to a commit.

Tracked content (usually most of the content in your repository) is sensitive to the branch that you've checked out. So if commit `D` above includes changes to `somefile.txt`, switching branches will cause `somefile.txt` to change.

Untracked content is entirely outside of Git's purview, and will not be modified at all when you change branches.

Comment: Ok, so I guess my question is..... what is the general method for physically separating the branches? Do you create another repo for `newbranch` that contains all the files or only the changed files? ...or how do you handle that?

Comment: @Brett, I'm not sure what you mean by "physically separating the branches". That phrase doesn't really make sense in this context. Could you add an example to your question that might clarify what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I guess branch was the wrong term. What I mean is what's the general method you use to separate the *files* that go in the two separate branches. Like, at the moment I just have the one repository with all the files in it and the master branch; now if I want to make some changes to some of the files they obviously can't be stored in the same place as the files will be different; so do you make a separate repository for all the files OR just the changed ones so that you can then use that to commit to the secondary branch?

Comment: @Brett, actually the files *are* stored in the same place. Simply modify your files as needed and commit. Now that you've recorded a new commit in one if your branches, Git will modify your working copy appropriately when you switch branches. (Git records the information necessary to do this in the `.git/` directory in your repository root.)

Comment: Hmmm ok. Confused at how that works though, as what if you make the changes to the actual files and then commit to the new branch. Now you wanna go back to work on the files for the main branch - won't the actual files still have the new changes in them that you made for the new branch?

Comment: @Brett, no. Assuming they're tracked, when you `git checkout master` Git will modify those files such that they match their versions from `master`. Why not give it a try in a test repository?

Comment: I tested it out and it all worked fine, except the first time I tried it and made changes in the new branch the file changes stayed on the master branch (though the removed files came back on master); then I tested it again and it worked. Not sure why as the master files had been committed prior to me committing the file changes on the new branch. Kinda weird.

Comment: @Brett, that may be because you didn't commit. Branches are relative to *commits*, not files. Until you commit your changes aren't on any branch; they're just sitting in your working directory.